# The column 'IncidentNumber' was specified multiple times for 'inv'

Tags: sql

I am having issue finding why I am having this [image: Error].

Here is the statement:

```
SELECT     Incident.salesrep AS Salesman, Incident.Incidentnumber AS Incidentent, bc.Name AS Customer, Incident.Address3 AS [Ship to Customer], Incident.UserText6 AS [Customer Type], 
                  inv.InvoiceNumber AS Invoice, sopHdr.DOCDATE AS [Document Date], sopHdr.GLPOSTDT AS [GL Post Date], 
                  CASE WHEN sopHdr.DOCAMNT < 0 THEN (sopHdr.DOCAMNT) WHEN (sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 AND sopHdr.DOCAMNT > 0) THEN (sopHdr.DOCAMNT * - 1) 
                  ELSE CASE WHEN Paid.Paid IS NULL THEN 0.00 ELSE Paid.Paid END END AS [Amount Received], CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 THEN (sopHdr.DOCAMNT * - 1) 
                  ELSE sopHdr.DOCAMNT END AS [Sales Amount], CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 THEN (inv.CostTotal * - 1) ELSE inv.CostTotal END AS [Ext Cost], 
                  CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 THEN (inv.TaxTotal * - 1) ELSE inv.TaxTotal END AS [Tax Amount], 
                  CASE WHEN Incident.UserText8 = 'AVATAX' THEN 'S' WHEN Incident.UserText8 = 'COGS' THEN 'U' ELSE 'X' END AS [Tax Type], 
                  CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 THEN ((sopHdr.DOCAMNT - inv.TaxTotal) * - 1) ELSE (sopHdr.DOCAMNT - inv.TaxTotal) END AS [Net Sales], 
                  CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 THEN ((sopHdr.SUBTOTAL - inv.TaxTotal - inv.CostTotal) * - 1) ELSE (sopHdr.SUBTOTAL - inv.TaxTotal - inv.CostTotal) 
                  END AS [Gross Profit], 
                  --CASE WHEN (Incident.UserText1 IS NULL OR
   --               Incident.UserText1 = '') THEN 0.00 ELSE CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 THEN (((sopHdr.DOCAMNT - inv.TaxTotal) - inv.CostTotal) * - 1) * (Incident.UserText1 / 100.0) 
   --               ELSE ((sopHdr.DOCAMNT - inv.TaxTotal) - inv.CostTotal) * (Incident.UserText1 / 100.0) END END AS [Accrued Commission],
                  --CASE WHEN (Incident.UserText1 IS NULL OR
   --               Incident.UserText1 = '') THEN '0.00' ELSE Incident.UserText1 END AS [Commission %], Incident.UserText21 AS [Not Commissionable], Incident.UserText18 AS [Date 1st Comm PD], 
                  CASE WHEN (sopHdr.SUBTOTAL IS NULL OR
                  sopHdr.SUBTOTAL = 0) THEN 0.00 
                    ELSE 
                    CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 THEN ((sopHdr.SUBTOTAL - inv.TaxTotal - inv.CostTotal) / (sopHdr.SUBTOTAL - inv.TaxTotal)) * - 100 
                        ELSE (((sopHdr.SUBTOTAL - inv.TaxTotal - inv.CostTotal) / (sopHdr.SUBTOTAL - inv.TaxTotal)) * 100) 
                  END END AS [Sale Gross Profit %], 
                  CASE WHEN (sopHdr.DOCAMNT < 0) OR
                  (sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 AND sopHdr.DOCAMNT > 0) THEN 100.00 
                    ELSE 
                        CASE WHEN (Paid.Paid IS NULL OR Paid.Paid = 0) OR (sopHdr.DOCAMNT = 0 OR sopHdr.DOCAMNT IS NULL) THEN 0.00 
                            ELSE (Paid.Paid / sopHdr.DOCAMNT) * 100 END END AS [Paid %], Incident.UserText25 AS Direct, Incident.UserText26 AS [Split w/Rep], 
                                    Incident.UserText27 AS [% of Job Rep 1], Incident.UserText28 AS [% of Job Rep 2], Incident.UserText23 AS [Date 2nd Comm PD], inv.InvoiceTotal AS [Invoiced Total]

FROM         (SELECT     Record, BatchNumber, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, Status, InvoiceType, InvoiceSource, ApplyTo, IncidentNumber, IncidentNumber, TaskID, 
                                          BillToCompanyID, BillToCompanyCode, BillToCompanyName, BillToAddressID, BillToAddressCode, BillToAddress1, BillToAddress2, BillToAddress3, 
                                          BillToAddress4, BillToCity, BillToState, BillToZip, BillToCountry, PONumber, BillingContactID, BillingFirstName, BillingLastName, BillingPhone, 
                                          BillingExtension, BillingEmail, IntegrationValue, InternalNotes, ExternalNotes, CreateDate, ModifyDate, EnteredByUser, ModifiedByUser, ContractNumber, 
                                          Division, IsEmailed, UserNotes, UserNotes2, DocumentType, PaymentTerms, TransferToBatchNumber, AdjustmentType, IsPaid, UserText1, UserText2, 
                                          UserText3, UserText4, UserText5, UserText6, UserText7, UserText8, UserText9, UserText10, UserDate1, UserDate2, UserDate3, UserNotes3,
                                              (SELECT     SUM(SalesAmount) AS Expr1
                                                FROM          AlertCRM.dbo.InvoiceDetail
                                                WHERE      (InvoiceRecord = AlertCRM.dbo.Invoice.Record)) AS SubTotal,
                                              (SELECT     SUM(SalesTax) AS Expr1
                                                FROM          AlertCRM.dbo.InvoiceDetail AS InvoiceDetail_3
                                                WHERE      (InvoiceRecord = AlertCRM.dbo.Invoice.Record)) AS TaxTotal,
                                              (SELECT     ISNULL(SUM(SalesAmount), 0) + ISNULL(SUM(SalesTax), 0) AS Expr1
                                                FROM          AlertCRM.dbo.InvoiceDetail AS InvoiceDetail_2
                                                WHERE      (InvoiceRecord = AlertCRM.dbo.Invoice.Record)) AS InvoiceTotal,
                                              (SELECT     SUM(CostAmount) AS Expr1
                                                FROM          AlertCRM.dbo.InvoiceDetail AS InvoiceDetail_1
                                                WHERE      (InvoiceRecord = AlertCRM.dbo.Invoice.Record)) AS CostTotal
                   FROM          AlertCRM.dbo.Invoice) AS inv INNER JOIN
                  AlertCRM.dbo.Incident AS Incident ON Incident.IncidentNumber = inv.IncidentNumber LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  AlertCRM.dbo.Company AS bc ON bc.CompanyID = Incident.BillingCompanyID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.SOP30200 AS sopHdr ON sopHdr.SOPNUMBE = inv.InvoiceNumber LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      (SELECT     APTODCNM AS Invoice, SUM(Paid) AS Paid
                        FROM          (SELECT     APTODCNM, SUM(ActualApplyToAmount) AS Paid
                                                FROM          dbo.RM20201
                                                GROUP BY APTODCNM
                                                UNION
                                                SELECT     APTODCNM, SUM(ActualApplyToAmount) AS Paid
                                                FROM         dbo.RM30201
                                                GROUP BY APTODCNM) AS p
                        GROUP BY APTODCNM) AS Paid ON Paid.Invoice = sopHdr.SOPNUMBE
```

Please advise.

Comment: Could you take out some of the code? It's easier for people to help you if you only show the relevant information :)

Comment: I would like too, but Code Snippet did not allow me add a query. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT Incident.salesrep AS Salesman,
       Incident.Incidentnumber AS Incidentent,
       bc.Name AS Customer,
       Incident.Address3 AS [Ship to Customer],
       Incident.UserText6 AS [Customer Type],
       inv.InvoiceNumber AS Invoice,
       sopHdr.DOCDATE AS [Document Date],
       sopHdr.GLPOSTDT AS [GL Post Date],
       CASE
           WHEN sopHdr.DOCAMNT < 0
           THEN(sopHdr.DOCAMNT)
           WHEN(sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4
                AND sopHdr.DOCAMNT > 0)
           THEN(sopHdr.DOCAMNT * -1)
           ELSE CASE
                    WHEN Paid.Paid IS NULL
                    THEN 0.00
                    ELSE Paid.Paid
                END
       END AS [Amount Received],
       CASE
           WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4
           THEN(sopHdr.DOCAMNT * -1)
           ELSE sopHdr.DOCAMNT
       END AS [Sales Amount],
       CASE
           WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4
           THEN(inv.CostTotal * -1)
           ELSE inv.CostTotal
       END AS [Ext Cost],
       CASE
           WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4
           THEN(inv.TaxTotal * -1)
           ELSE inv.TaxTotal
       END AS [Tax Amount],
       CASE
           WHEN Incident.UserText8 = 'AVATAX'
           THEN 'S'
           WHEN Incident.UserText8 = 'COGS'
           THEN 'U'
           ELSE 'X'
       END AS [Tax Type],
       CASE
           WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4
           THEN((sopHdr.DOCAMNT - inv.TaxTotal) * -1)
           ELSE(sopHdr.DOCAMNT - inv.TaxTotal)
       END AS [Net Sales],
       CASE
           WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4
           THEN((sopHdr.SUBTOTAL - inv.TaxTotal - inv.CostTotal) * -1)
           ELSE(sopHdr.SUBTOTAL - inv.TaxTotal - inv.CostTotal)
       END AS [Gross Profit]
FROM
(
    SELECT Record,
           BatchNumber,
           InvoiceNumber,
           InvoiceDate,
           Status,
           InvoiceType,
           InvoiceSource,
           ApplyTo,
           IncidentNumber,    
           TaskID,
           BillToCompanyID,
           BillToCompanyCode,
           BillToCompanyName,
           BillToAddressID,
           BillToAddressCode,
           BillToAddress1,
           BillToAddress2,
           BillToAddress3,
           BillToAddress4,
           BillToCity,
           BillToState,
           BillToZip,
           BillToCountry,
           PONumber,
           BillingContactID,
           BillingFirstName,
           BillingLastName,
           BillingPhone,
           BillingExtension,
           BillingEmail,
           IntegrationValue,
           InternalNotes,
           ExternalNotes,
           CreateDate,
           ModifyDate,
           EnteredByUser,
           ModifiedByUser,
           ContractNumber,
           Division,
           IsEmailed,
           UserNotes,
           UserNotes2,
           DocumentType,
           PaymentTerms,
           TransferToBatchNumber,
           AdjustmentType,
           IsPaid,
           UserText1,
           UserText2,
           UserText3,
           UserText4,
           UserText5,
           UserText6,
           UserText7,
           UserText8,
           UserText9,
           UserText10,
           UserDate1,
           UserDate2,
           UserDate3,
           UserNotes3,
    (
        SELECT SUM(SalesAmount) AS Expr1
        FROM AlertCRM.dbo.InvoiceDetail
        WHERE(InvoiceRecord = AlertCRM.dbo.Invoice.Record)
    ) AS SubTotal,
    (
        SELECT SUM(SalesTax) AS Expr1
        FROM AlertCRM.dbo.InvoiceDetail AS InvoiceDetail_3
        WHERE(InvoiceRecord = AlertCRM.dbo.Invoice.Record)
    ) AS TaxTotal,
    (
        SELECT ISNULL(SUM(SalesAmount), 0) + ISNULL(SUM(SalesTax), 0) AS Expr1
        FROM AlertCRM.dbo.InvoiceDetail AS InvoiceDetail_2
        WHERE(InvoiceRecord = AlertCRM.dbo.Invoice.Record)
    ) AS InvoiceTotal,
    (
        SELECT SUM(CostAmount) AS Expr1
        FROM AlertCRM.dbo.InvoiceDetail AS InvoiceDetail_1
        WHERE(InvoiceRecord = AlertCRM.dbo.Invoice.Record)
    ) AS CostTotal
    FROM AlertCRM.dbo.Invoice
) AS inv
INNER JOIN AlertCRM.dbo.Incident AS Incident ON Incident.IncidentNumber = inv.IncidentNumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN AlertCRM.dbo.Company AS bc ON bc.CompanyID = Incident.BillingCompanyID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SOP30200 AS sopHdr ON sopHdr.SOPNUMBE = inv.InvoiceNumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT APTODCNM AS Invoice,
           SUM(Paid) AS Paid
    FROM
    (
        SELECT APTODCNM,
               SUM(ActualApplyToAmount) AS Paid
        FROM dbo.RM20201
        GROUP BY APTODCNM
        UNION
        SELECT APTODCNM,
               SUM(ActualApplyToAmount) AS Paid
        FROM dbo.RM30201
        GROUP BY APTODCNM
    ) AS p
    GROUP BY APTODCNM
) AS Paid ON Paid.Invoice = sopHdr.SOPNUMBE;
```

Comment: That is working till you add series of the cases. I need them to calculate commission an profit. Also, I have an issue dividing by 0 there anyone can help.

Comment: Check original query starting CASE 
   WHEN (Incident.UserText1 IS NULL OR Incident.UserText1 = '') 
   THEN 0.00 
   ELSE ..... and ending END AS [Paid %], Incident.UserText25 AS Direct,...  Thanks

Comment: here is what am getting: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: I got it going. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need FROM with inv there. Remove that. Try following query.

```
SELECT Incident.salesrep AS Salesman,
 Incident.Incidentnumber AS Incidentent,
 bc.Name AS Customer,
 Incident.Address3 AS [Ship to Customer], 
 Incident.UserText6 AS [Customer Type], 
 inv.InvoiceNumber AS Invoice,
 sopHdr.DOCDATE AS [Document Date], 
 sopHdr.GLPOSTDT AS [GL Post Date], 
 CASE WHEN sopHdr.DOCAMNT < 0 THEN (sopHdr.DOCAMNT) WHEN (sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 AND sopHdr.DOCAMNT > 0) THEN (sopHdr.DOCAMNT * - 1) ELSE CASE WHEN Paid.Paid IS NULL THEN 0.00 ELSE Paid.Paid END END AS [Amount Received], CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 THEN (sopHdr.DOCAMNT * - 1) ELSE sopHdr.DOCAMNT END AS [Sales Amount], CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 THEN (inv.CostTotal * - 1) ELSE inv.CostTotal END AS [Ext Cost], CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 THEN (inv.TaxTotal * - 1) ELSE inv.TaxTotal END AS [Tax Amount], CASE WHEN Incident.UserText8 = 'AVATAX' THEN 'S' WHEN Incident.UserText8 = 'COGS' THEN 'U' ELSE 'X' END AS [Tax Type], CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 THEN ((sopHdr.DOCAMNT - inv.TaxTotal) * - 1) ELSE (sopHdr.DOCAMNT - inv.TaxTotal) END AS [Net Sales], CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 THEN ((sopHdr.SUBTOTAL - inv.TaxTotal - inv.CostTotal) * - 1) ELSE (sopHdr.SUBTOTAL - inv.TaxTotal - inv.CostTotal) END AS [Gross Profit], --CASE WHEN (Incident.UserText1 IS NULL OR -- Incident.UserText1 = '') THEN 0.00 ELSE CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 THEN (((sopHdr.DOCAMNT - inv.TaxTotal) - inv.CostTotal) * - 1) * (Incident.UserText1 / 100.0) -- ELSE ((sopHdr.DOCAMNT - inv.TaxTotal) - inv.CostTotal) * (Incident.UserText1 / 100.0) END END AS [Accrued Commission], --CASE WHEN (Incident.UserText1 IS NULL OR -- Incident.UserText1 = '') THEN '0.00' ELSE Incident.UserText1 END AS [Commission %], Incident.UserText21 AS [Not Commissionable], Incident.UserText18 AS [Date 1st Comm PD], CASE WHEN (sopHdr.SUBTOTAL IS NULL OR sopHdr.SUBTOTAL = 0) THEN 0.00 ELSE CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 THEN ((sopHdr.SUBTOTAL - inv.TaxTotal - inv.CostTotal) / (sopHdr.SUBTOTAL - inv.TaxTotal)) * - 100 ELSE (((sopHdr.SUBTOTAL - inv.TaxTotal - inv.CostTotal) / (sopHdr.SUBTOTAL - inv.TaxTotal)) * 100) END END AS [Sale Gross Profit %], CASE WHEN (sopHdr.DOCAMNT < 0) OR (sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 AND sopHdr.DOCAMNT > 0) THEN 100.00 ELSE CASE WHEN (Paid.Paid IS NULL OR Paid.Paid = 0) OR (sopHdr.DOCAMNT = 0 OR sopHdr.DOCAMNT IS NULL) THEN 0.00 ELSE (Paid.Paid / sopHdr.DOCAMNT) * 100 END END AS [Paid %], Incident.UserText25 AS Direct,
 Incident.UserText26 AS [Split w/Rep], Incident.UserText27 AS [% of Job Rep 1], Incident.UserText28 AS [% of Job Rep 2], Incident.UserText23 AS [Date 2nd Comm PD], inv.InvoiceTotal AS [Invoiced Total]
FROM (SELECT Record,
 BatchNumber,
 InvoiceNumber,
 InvoiceDate,
 Status,
 InvoiceType,
 InvoiceSource,
 ApplyTo,
 IncidentNumber,
 IncidentNumber,
 TaskID,
 BillToCompanyID,
 BillToCompanyCode,
 BillToCompanyName,
 BillToAddressID,
 BillToAddressCode,
 BillToAddress1,
 BillToAddress2,
 BillToAddress3,
 BillToAddress4,
 BillToCity,
 BillToState,
 BillToZip,
 BillToCountry,
 PONumber,
 BillingContactID,
 BillingFirstName,
 BillingLastName,
 BillingPhone,
 BillingExtension,
 BillingEmail,
 IntegrationValue,
 InternalNotes,
 ExternalNotes,
 CreateDate,
 ModifyDate,
 EnteredByUser,
 ModifiedByUser,
 ContractNumber,
 Division,
 IsEmailed,
 UserNotes,
 UserNotes2,
 DocumentType,
 PaymentTerms,
 TransferToBatchNumber,
 AdjustmentType,
 IsPaid,
 UserText1,
 UserText2,
 UserText3,
 UserText4,
 UserText5,
 UserText6,
 UserText7,
 UserText8,
 UserText9,
 UserText10,
 UserDate1,
 UserDate2,
 UserDate3,
 UserNotes3,
 (SELECT SUM(SalesAmount) AS Expr1 FROM AlertCRM.dbo.InvoiceDetail WHERE (InvoiceRecord = AlertCRM.dbo.Invoice.Record)) AS SubTotal,
 (SELECT SUM(SalesTax) AS Expr1 FROM AlertCRM.dbo.InvoiceDetail AS InvoiceDetail_3 WHERE (InvoiceRecord = AlertCRM.dbo.Invoice.Record)) AS TaxTotal,
 (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(SalesAmount), 0) + ISNULL(SUM(SalesTax), 0) AS Expr1 FROM AlertCRM.dbo.InvoiceDetail AS InvoiceDetail_2 WHERE (InvoiceRecord = AlertCRM.dbo.Invoice.Record)) AS InvoiceTotal,
 (SELECT SUM(CostAmount) AS Expr1 
 FROM AlertCRM.dbo.InvoiceDetail AS InvoiceDetail_1 WHERE (InvoiceRecord = AlertCRM.dbo.Invoice.Record)) AS CostTotal, 
 Incident.Invoice AS inv 
INNER JOIN AlertCRM.dbo.Incident AS Incident ON Incident.IncidentNumber = inv.IncidentNumber LEFT OUTER JOIN AlertCRM.dbo.Company AS bc ON bc.CompanyID = Incident.BillingCompanyID LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SOP30200 AS sopHdr ON sopHdr.SOPNUMBE = inv.InvoiceNumber LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT APTODCNM AS Invoice,
 SUM(Paid) AS Paid FROM (SELECT APTODCNM,
 SUM(ActualApplyToAmount) AS Paid FROM dbo.RM20201 GROUP BY APTODCNM UNION SELECT APTODCNM,
 SUM(ActualApplyToAmount) AS Paid FROM dbo.RM30201 GROUP BY APTODCNM) AS p GROUP BY APTODCNM) AS Paid ON Paid.Invoice = sopHdr.SOPNUMBE
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 79
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 82
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.